# Rename node with specific value with XLST2 tunneling

Tags: xslt

I am trying to rename nodes, that have specific value in them. I want to use XSLT2 with tunneling, but i am stuck and dont know what is wrong.

XML i have

```
<root>
<node1>xxx</node1>
<node2>some other data</node2>
..
..
..
</root>
```

XML i want

```
<root>
<node1x>xxx</node1x>
<node2>some other data</node2>
..
..
..
</root>
```

XSLT i am using

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:param name="suffix" tunnel="yes" select="''" />
<xsl:element name="{name()}{$suffix}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/node1/xxx"><xsl:next-match><xsl:with-param name="suffix" tunnel="yes" select="'x'" /></xsl:next-match></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does not work, and i cant figure out why not? Can somebody help?

Thanks a lot,
e.

SOLUTION:
This is solution i came up with help of user below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="suffix" tunnel="yes" select="''" />
    <xsl:element name="{name()}{$suffix}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/node1[. = 'xxx']"><xsl:next-match><xsl:with-param name="suffix" tunnel="yes" select="'x'" /></xsl:next-match></xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `match="root/node1[. = 'xxx']"` instead of `match="root/node1/xxx"`.

I am not sure why you think you need to use a tunnel parameter and next match, I think you can just code

```
<xsl:template match="root/node1[. = 'xxx']">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}x" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Basically you solution is not what i had in mind but it helped me figure it out what was wrong:D. Solution is above. Thanks.

Comment: Did you even checked supplied answer above, and my solution? BTW, i have always confirmed correct answer on this site and i dont need nobody to remind me when i have to confirm it - for that i have my wife :D Today is no different, but maybe only my time frame is of some concern to you.